# React Native props.value is not defined

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I am just new on React Native. I made a Login screen and a Loggedin screen. My username and password take a token from webAPI and print a data to Loggedin screen from webAPI.

Now I want to prepare a drawer navigation. I need to send the token from below code to Loggedin screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Loading } from '../components/common';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Content, Icon, Header, Body } from 'native-base'
import { DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems, SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation'
import Logged from './LoggedIn'
import Home from './HomeScreen'
import DeviceStroge from '../services/deviceStorage'



class DrawerNavigationScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.jwt)
    this.state = {
      loading: true,

      email: '',
      error: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CustomDrawer />
    );
  }
}



const CustomDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Loggedin: { screen:(props)=>  <Logged {...props} myjwt={this.props.jwt}/> },
  Test: { screen: Home }

}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Loggedin',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
  }
)

export default DrawerNavigationScreen;
```

The 'jwt' is a string that keeps token. I can see the token in the console, but it throws

> Cannot read property 'jwt' of undefined.

This is probably because of `DrawerNavigator` property. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the props of `DrawerNavigationScreen` outside of it: since `CustomDrawer` is defined outside the component class, it does not have access to either `props` or `state`.

**Option 1**: You could try to move the use of `DrawerNavigator()` in the render function like in this:

```
class DrawerNavigationScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.jwt)
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      email: '',
      error: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return DrawerNavigator({
      Loggedin: { screen:(props)=>  <Logged {...props} myjwt={this.props.jwt}/> },
      Test: { screen: Home }
    }, {
      initialRouteName: 'Loggedin',
      drawerPosition: 'right',
      drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
      drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
      drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Option 2**: A cleaner alternative would be to make `CustomDrawer` a function that accepts a parameter `jwt`:

```
const CustomDrawer = (jwt) => DrawerNavigator({
  Loggedin: { screen:(props)=>  <Logged {...props} myjwt={jwt}/> },
  Test: { screen: Home }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Loggedin',
  drawerPosition: 'right',
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
});
```

And then you have to pass the `jwt` as a prop in the render function:

```
// From DrawerNavigationScreen component.
render() {
  return <CustomDrawer jwt={this.props.jwt}/>
}
```